# Concentration cell lower half cell concentration from measured cell potential

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, solubility, concentration

I am trying to find the K<sub>sp</sub> of silver thiocyanate:
AgSCN<sub>(s)</sub> --> Ag<sup>+</sup> <sub>(aq)</sub>SCN<sup>-</sup><sub>(aq)</sub>

but I need to first prove that the **lower** [Ag+] = 1.27<sup>-12</sup> M, but don't know how to find it.

The data I am given:
Volume of 10<sup>-4</sup> M Ag+ solution used: 10.00ml

Volume of 1.0 M KSCN added: 50.00ml

Measured cell potential when an Ag(s) electrode was placed into the above mixture, and then joined to the Ag+(0.1M)/Ag(s) half cell: 0.645V

Results:
Calculated lower [Ag+] from cell potential: 1.27<sup>-12</sup> M

I am suppose to use this equation for the concentration cell:

[image]

where n is the number of electrons.

So really my question is how I would go about finding the higher concentration of Ag<sup>+</sup> and then use that to determine that **lower** [Ag+] = 1.27<sup>-12</sup>M

Comment: Can you define what lower and higher mean? A sketch of your cell could be useful.

Comment: This is a concentration cell, which has the same components in each half cell, but the concentrations are not standard (1mol/L) and the difference in concentration results in an electrode potential. By higher I mean the half cell with a higher concentration of Ag+ which is the cathode half cell, and the lower concentration half cell is the anode. So the net cell reaction is Ag+(higher)-->Ag+(lower) and thus the Nernst equation is [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eVZRd.gif) The idea is that the concentration of SCN- is much larger than the **lower** concentration of Ag+